# Just bought MBPr and cannot connect to appstore

Tags: mac, macos, ios-appstore, login, internet

Whenever I try to connect to app store I got this error:

[image: error]

I tried everything I could find in internet, but always the same problem.

OSX: Yosemite
Model: MBPr 15 mid-2014

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Check the date and time / timezone. If it's incorrect you won't be able to connect to the App Store (or much else for that matter.)

Comment: To avoid having your answer downvoted, you should edit it to add supporting links or personal info explaining how the answer worked for you.  Simply making the statement you have would be considered a poor answer (especially to a 2 year-old question).

Answer (score 0):

Try it with a different internet connection.